# Handwritten linked list is segfaulting and I don't understand why

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

Hi I was working on a bit of fun, making an interface to run gnuplot from within c++, and for some reason the my linked list implementation fails.

The code below fails on the line `plots->append(&plot)`. Stepping through the code I discovered that for some reason the destructor `~John()` is called immediately after the constructor `John()`, and I cannot seem to figure out why.

The code included below is a stripped down version operating only on `Plot*`. Originally I made the linked list as a template class. And it worked fine as `ll<int>` and `ll<char*>` but for some reason it fails as `ll<Plot*>`.

Could youp please help me figure out why it fails? and perhaps help me understand how to make it work?

In advance: Thanks a heap!

//B2S

```
#include <string.h>

class Plot{
  char title[80];
public:
  Plot(){  }
};

class Link{
  Plot* element;
  Link* next;
  Link* prev;
  friend class ll;
};

class ll{
  Link* head;
  Link* tail;
public:
  ll(){
    head = tail = new Link();
    head->prev = tail->prev = head->next = tail->next = head;
  }
  ~ll(){
    while (head!=tail){
      tail = tail->prev;
      delete tail->next;
    }
    delete head;
  }
  void append(Plot* element){
    tail->element = element;
    tail->next = new Link();
    tail->next->prev = tail;
    tail->next = tail;
  }
};

class John{
  ll* plots;
public:
  John(){
   plots= new ll();
  }
  ~John(){
    delete plots;
  }
  John(Plot* plot){
    John();
    plots->append(plot);
  }
};   

int main(){
  Plot p;
  John k(&p);
}
```

Comment: In the face of fierce competition, you have come up with one of the most incomprehensible linked list implementations I have ever seen. Why not use std::list, if you feel the need to use this benighted type of data structure at all?

Comment: And who is voting this question up? And why?

Comment: The above was never meant to be a full and proper implementation, merely a stripped down, highlighting what did not work in the implementation I was working on. Why not use std::list? I just prefer practice to magic, is all :)

Comment: It seems fairly straightforward to me. I'm not sure why you're using dynamic allocation for plots, though; it should work fine as (non-pointer) member variable, and then you don't have to worry about allocating it. Also you wouldn't need the destructor for John; it would all be done automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement:

```
 John();
```

Just constructs a new nameless John which is created and immediately destroyed. There is no way (in the current version of C++) to call a constructor from another constructor or on an already constructed object.

This means that the `plots` member of your `John` called `k` is never being initalized, hence the crash when you call `append` from the `John` constructor.

[As Neil Butterworth comments, if you had actually constructed an `ll` instance there are other issues with it, this is just the most immediate problem.]

Comment: ah, Thanks! You seem to have hit the nail spot on. Fixing that, it compiles and runs beautifully.

Comment: Sure you can call a constructor from another constructor:  `John(Plot* plot):John(){
    plots->append(plot);
  }`

Comment: @ALFlanagan: Not for the same object in C++03, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

Because you can't call alternate constructors like that in C++. In...

```
John(Plot* plot){
  John();
  plots->append(plot);
}
```

Your first line constructs a new `John` object using the default constructor, then throws the result away. It then calls `append` on `plots` (which as it has not been set to anything, is junk). Refactor the real `plots` initialisation code into a private method, then call this `init` method in both constructors before doing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

```
head = tail = new Link();
```

Here you assign head and tail to point to the same link object. Since you never reassign either of them, that means that any time you change any property of head (e.g. `head.next = foo`), the same change is applied to tail.

Meaning head and tail will always have the same element, the predecessor and the same successor. Obviously this does not lead to the intended results.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Plot p;
  John k(&p);
```

Use this instead:

```
  Plot * p = (Plot*) new Plot;
  John k(p);
```

This code is broken, since once p goes out of scope, k's reference to it will die.  This is not the bug that caused the segfault, but it will probably cause a segfault later on once you fix your other bugs.

You will need to delete p later.